# Reordering LabelNodes causes their offset to mess up in Java ASM

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I have the following sample code:

```
    Label L1654589030
    Line 3, L1654589030
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init>()V
    RETURN
    Label L466002798
```

I perform a basic transformation, reordering instructions and labels and inserting two `GOTO` instructions:

```
    GOTO L1654589030
    Label L466002798
    RETURN
    Label L1654589030
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init>()V
    GOTO L466002798
```

However, when frames are being calculated by ASM, it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at `org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.createDebugLabel`. In `createDebugLabel`, ASM tries to access a label at offset `65539`, thus crashing. I can work this issue around by replacing the `LabelNode` I moved `up` with a new `LabelNode`, but that means I'll also have to update all instructions referencing it. Why is issue occurring?

**EDIT1 |** `CheckClassAdapter` returns the following dump:

```
<init>()V
00000 Main  :  :     GOTO L0
00001 Main  :  :    L1
00002 Main  :  :    FRAME FULL [com/company/Main] []
00003 Main  :  :     RETURN
00004 Main  :  :    L0
00005 Main  :  :    FRAME FULL [U] []
00006 Main  :  :     ALOAD 0
00007 Main  : Main  :     INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
00008 Main  :  :     GOTO L1
```

`FRAME FULL` should not be there, but how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** The `MethodNode.localVariables` -> `start` / `end` labels didn't form a region after I reordered their instruction nodes. I had to manually update each variable.